# Associative Array PHP Random values

Tags: php, arrays

i have a questing regarding associates multidimensional arrays in php.

Let's say i have the following table:

```
Product Nr  Img
kat1    abc abc.png
kat1    xyz xyz.png
kat2    def def.png
kat2    gfh gfh.png
kat2    jug jug.png
kat3    lkj lkj.png
kat3    tfh tfh.png
kat4    fsg fsg.png
kat4    gzt gzt.png
```

Building an array like:

```
$table= array(
  array("Product" => "Kat1","Nr" =>"abc","IMG" =>"abc.png"),
  array("Product" => "Kat1","Nr" =>"xyz","IMG" =>"xyz.png"),
  array("Product" => "Kat2","Nr" =>"def","IMG" =>"def.png"),
  array("Product" => "Kat2","Nr" =>"gfh","IMG" =>"gfh.png"),
  array("Product" => "Kat2","Nr" =>"jug","IMG" =>"jug.png"),
  array("Product" => "Kat3","Nr" =>"lkj","IMG" =>"lkj.png"),
  array("Product" => "Kat3","Nr" =>"tfh","IMG" =>"tfh.png"),
  array("Product" => "Kat4","Nr" =>"fsg","IMG" =>"fsg.png"),
  array("Product" => "Kat4","Nr" =>"gzt","IMG" =>"gzt.png"),

  );
```

i want to built random productsets. and every productsets should contain one product from every single kategorie. for example the following output:

```
Kat1 = abc, abc.png
Kat2 = gfh, gfh.png
Kat3 = lkj, lkj.png
Kat4 = gzt, gzt.png
```

I'm not sure if i'm on the right way or if its possible with that kind of array. Any Ideas how i can solve that?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Can you please explain some more about what you exactly want? as you mentioned "Kat1 = abc, abc.png", is not much clear to identify your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this mysql query to get desired result:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        product
    ORDER BY RAND()) AS shuffled_products
GROUP BY PRODUCT;
```

Once you received the result array in php using loop manipulate it to desired result.

Comment: @swapfile this query is not optimized for performance. Hope you take care of that. Instead of `*` chose only the column you need.

Answer (score 1):

1) Try rebuild your array in view like this (group by categories):

```
$tableGroupByCats = [
    "Kat1" => [
        ["Nr" =>"abc","IMG" =>"abc.png"],
        ["Nr" =>"xyz","IMG" =>"xyz.png"]
    ],
    "Kat2" => [
        ["Nr" =>"def","IMG" =>"def.png"],
        ["Nr" =>"gfh","IMG" =>"gfh.png"],
        ["Nr" =>"jug","IMG" =>"jug.png"]
    ],
    "Kat3" => [
        "Nr" =>"lkj","IMG" =>"lkj.png",
        "Nr" =>"tfh","IMG" =>"tfh.png"
    ],
    "Kat4" => [
        ["Nr" =>"fsg","IMG" =>"fsg.png"],
        ["Nr" =>"gzt","IMG" =>"gzt.png"]
    ]
];
```

following code will help you:

```
$table= array(
    array("Product" => "Kat1","Nr" =>"abc","IMG" =>"abc.png"),
    array("Product" => "Kat1","Nr" =>"xyz","IMG" =>"xyz.png"),
    array("Product" => "Kat2","Nr" =>"def","IMG" =>"def.png"),
    array("Product" => "Kat2","Nr" =>"gfh","IMG" =>"gfh.png"),
    array("Product" => "Kat2","Nr" =>"jug","IMG" =>"jug.png"),
    array("Product" => "Kat3","Nr" =>"lkj","IMG" =>"lkj.png"),
    array("Product" => "Kat3","Nr" =>"tfh","IMG" =>"tfh.png"),
    array("Product" => "Kat4","Nr" =>"fsg","IMG" =>"fsg.png"),
    array("Product" => "Kat4","Nr" =>"gzt","IMG" =>"gzt.png"),

);

$tableGroupByCats = [];
foreach ($table as $product) {
    $tableGroupByCats[$product['Product']][] = ["Nr" => $product["Nr"], "IMG" => $product["IMG"]];
}
```

Or you can retrieve array like that from DB using GROUP BY

2) Get your result:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($tableGroupByCats as $ctegory => $products) {
    $randNum = mt_rand(0, (count($products)-1));
    $result[$ctegory] = $products[$randNum];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it:

Code:

```
shuffle($table);
foreach($table as $row){
    $result[$row["Product"]]="{$row["Product"]} = {$row["Nr"]}, {$row["IMG"]}"; // overwrite duplicates
}
ksort($result);  // sort result array by Product ASC
var_export($result);
```

Possible Output:

```
array (
  'Kat1' => 'Kat1 = xyz, xyz.png',
  'Kat2' => 'Kat2 = jug, jug.png',
  'Kat3' => 'Kat3 = lkj, lkj.png',
  'Kat4' => 'Kat4 = gzt, gzt.png',
)
```